# Update Attribute Based on Update of Hash

Tags: ruby

I have a project where I am dynamically creating attributes on a class and these attributes are also stored as a hash in another property that serves as a collection of all of these attributes and their values.  What I'd like to be able to do is update the attribute when the hash is updated and vice versa.

Something like this:

```
class SomeClass


  def initialize
    #code that creates the attributes on the class
    config_list.each { |config| self.class.send(:attr_accessor, config) }
  end

  #list of attributes that are dynamically added to the class
  #this is normally read from a config file but I added it here to simplify
  def config_list
    [:abc, :def, :ghi]
  end

  def configuration
    config_list.inject({}) do |r,e| 
      r[e] = instance_variable_get("@#{e.to_s}"); r 
    end
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
x = SomeClass.new
  #=> #<SomeClass:0x007f9931990710>
x.abc = 5
  #=> 5
x.configuration
  #=> {:abc=>5, :def=>nil, :ghi=>nil}
x.configuration[:abc] = 10
  #=> 10
x.abc
  #=> 5
```

I'd like that final last call of:

```
x.abc
```

to return 10 because the configuration's value was updated.  Is that possible?  If so, how do I do it?

Comment: @engineersmnky would that work both ways though?  I would like "@configuration" to get updated when the "@abc" is updated and "@abc" updated when "@configuration" is updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an expanded example of what I believe you are trying to achieve.

I Created a class for `Configuration` to manage predefined keys so that you cannot manipulate the keys in the hash. I only gave it access to `[]` and `[]=` and added `to_h` for `Hash` but duped the `@configuration` so you can't manipulate it through there either.

```
class SomeClass
  # build this list in anyway you see fit 
  PREDEFINED_KEYS =  [:abc, :def, :ghi] 
  # define getter/setter methods for the PREDEFINED_KEYS
  PREDEFINED_KEYS.each do |m|
    define_method(m) do 
      @configuration[m] 
    end
    define_method("#{m}=") do |val|
      @configuration[m] = val
    end
  end 
  # intialize a new Configuration with the PREDEFINED_KEYS
  def initialize
    @configuration = Configuration.new(PREDEFINED_KEYS)
  end
  # alternate implementation using initialize instead of a constant
  # def initialize(keys)
  #   @configuration = Configuration.new(keys)
  #   instance_eval do 
  #     keys.each do |m|
  #       define_singleton_method(m) do 
  #         @configuration[m] 
  #       end
  #       define_singleton_method("#{m}=") do |val|
  #         @configuration[m] = val
  #       end
  #     end
  #   end
  # end
  # Usage: SomeClass.new([:abc,:def,:ghi])

  # accept a block and return the configuration class
  def configuration
    yield @configuration if block_given? 
    @configuration 
  end
  # convert to a proper Hash
  def to_h
    @configuration.to_h
  end

  class Configuration
    class UndefinedKeyError < StandardError;end
    # start out all keys with a value of nil
    def initialize(keys)
      @configuration = Hash[keys.product([nil])]
    end
    # retrieve value by key just like a normal Hash
    def [](k)
      @configuration[k]
    end
    # set value by key like a normal Hash 
    # excepting the key must be one of the keys defined in initialization
    def []=(k,v)
      raise(UndefinedKeyError, "must be one of #{@configuration.keys}") unless @configuration.has_key?(k)
      @configuration[k] = v
    end
    def to_h
      @configuration.dup
    end
  end
end
```

Then your use case should work appropriately. All you have to do is read out the keys from your file in place of the statically defined `PREDEFINED_KEYS`

Usage

```
s = SomeClass.new
s.abc = 12
s.to_h
#=> {abc: 12, def: nil, ghi: nil}
s.configuration[:def] = 19
s.to_h
#=> {abc: 12, def: 19, ghi: nil}
s.configuration do |c|
  c[:ghi] = 22
end.to_h
#=> {abc: 12, def: 19, ghi: 22}
s.ghi
#=> 22
s.configuration[:rbc] = 19
#=> SomeClass::Configuration::UndefinedKeyError: must be one of [:abc, :def, :ghi]
s.configuration[:lmn]
#=> nil
```

Comment: This is great.  I don't see your implementation of the Configuration class.  Can you post that please?

Comment: Nevermind i see it.  didn't scroll down in the code block.  Thanks!